# DuckDuckGo directed me to a rip-off site "stackovernet.com" in first page result

Tags: discussion, copyright, copycat-sites

Here is an example the rip-off is apparently monetizing through add (sometime even pr0n).
Is this site already known and under investigation?

Rip-off : https://gis.stackovernet.com/fr/q/9964

Original:
[How to do bivariate or multicriteria line symbolization in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32903/how-to-do-bivariate-or-multicriteria-line-symbolization-in-qgis)

PS: The site goes as far as duplicating a whole range of sub-sites and as one can see at top level site https://stackovernet.com

Comment: As per the duplicate, there is nothing illegal about this site. It has attribution under each post, and also mentions that content is licensed CC-BY_SA 3.0. Only thing that might be off is that I'm not sure how they handle different license versions that SO uses.

Comment: Fascinating.  It looks like it takes Stack Exchange content and Google Translates it into various other languages.